# Search for text in PDF using iText7 and get back entire box text

Tags: .net, pdf, search, itext

VB2017 using iText7. I am looking for a method to search for key text in a PDF. When I locate the key text I want to return all text within the box that it resides in.

For example, in this PDF I look for the key phrase "usable length" and want to return the text in the box where it was found "Rwy 33 PAPI-L, usable length, notes."

[image]

Here is what I have so far ([based on this](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy)) and would like any suggestions or advice on the concept:

```vbnet
    Public Function FindTextInPdfFile(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal searchText As String, ByVal IsCaseSensitive As Boolean) As List(Of String)
        'basic checks
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName) Then Return Nothing
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText) Then Return Nothing
        If Not File.Exists(fileName) Then Return Nothing

        'setup the regex to use or not use case sensitivity in the match
        Dim pattern As String = String.Format("({0})", searchText)
        Dim regEx As Regex = Nothing
        If IsCaseSensitive Then
            regEx = New Regex(pattern)
        Else
            regEx = New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        End If

        'setup the extraction strategy and temp buffer
        Dim strategy As ITextExtractionStrategy = New SimpleTextExtractionStrategy
        Dim buffBasic As New StringBuilder

        'open the PDF and do a basic search for the text in each page. for each page where we detect the search item
        'we will add that to the temp buffer.
        Using pdfReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(fileName)
            Using pdfDocument As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(pdfReader)
                For pageNum As Integer = 1 To pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages
                    Dim page As PdfPage = pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNum)
                    Dim currentPageText As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy)

                    If regEx.Matches(currentPageText).Count > 0 Then
                        'Debug.Print("found search text [{0}] in page num {1}", searchText, pageNum)
                        'Debug.Print("GetResultantText={0}", strategy.GetResultantText)

                        'GetResultantText has lines of text separated by an LF
                        buffBasic.Append(strategy.GetResultantText & lf)
                    End If
                Next pageNum
            End Using
        End Using

        'the buffer should have lines of text separated by an LF
        Dim linesBasic As List(Of String) = buffBasic.ToString.Split(lf).ToList
        Dim linesMatch As List(Of String) = linesBasic.FindAll(Function(x) regEx.Matches(x).Count > 0)
        Debug.Print("match count={0}", linesMatch.Count)
        For Each line In linesMatch
            Debug.Print("line={0}", line)
        Next line

        Return linesMatch
    End Function
```

Testing this on a sample PDF results in

```
FindTextInPdfFile(pdf, "usable length", True)
match count=1
line=Rwy 33 PAPI-L, usable length, notes.
```

Comment: How are the boxes created? Are there stoked lines around it? Or thin rectangles? Or a bitmap image background? If you are not sure, please share a representative example pdf.  And do you mean the thinly lined  boxes or the thickly lined cell boxes?

Comment: The boxes that are shown are only for demonstration. When I open a PDF in Acrobat Pro I can select Edit>Edit Text & Images and the boxes are drawn around text boxes. These editing boxes are denoted by the thinly lined boxes.

Comment: Ok, so those boxes regularly are *not* visible in the PDF... but what are they? Are they the text objects? Clip paths? Something else entirely? If you are not sure, please share a representative example pdf.

Comment: They are just text objects.

Comment: In that case it should suffice to extend the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` (which you use in your code) to also listen to the `BEGIN_TEXT` and `END_TEXT` event types. In case of such events, the extension may add specific markers to the text (using `appendTextChunk`). Or you might even split up the text into an array of texts (each one representing a text object).

Answer (score 0):

where page = PdfPage

```
    /// <summary>
    /// determines if this document contains the provided text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="find">string</param>
    /// <param name="caseSensitive">bool</param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public bool Contains(string find, bool caseSensitive = true)
    {
        string content = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return content.IndexOf(find, caseSensitive ? StringComparison.InvariantCulture : StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
    }
```

Comment: The OP said *"When I locate the key text I want to return all text within the box that it resides in."* Does your `bool` return value convey *all text within the box* of the match?